# How to color in progress on project tracker Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[image: Excel Screenshot]

I'm working on a project tracker in Excel and as you can see on the bottom right hand side is a progress bar that shows the duration of each project. Blue means in progress and populates the length of the project and the orange is %completed of it which is a visual of column AD. The problem is that I cannot get the %completed to color right. For example, durations that are only a day long: if I have 100% in column AD it will not only color the square its designated to, but two more blocks to the right making it look as if it is a 3 day long task. In addition, if I set 50% for example in the first task, it will cover about 90% of the bar. Here is the formula i use in conditional formatting.

***Orange:***`=AND($AD14>5%, $Z14<=AF$5,ROUNDDOWN(NETWORKDAYS($Z14,$AA14)*$AD14,0)+$Z14+1>=AF$5)`
***Blue:***`=AND(NOT(ISBLANK($Z13)),$Z13<=AF$10,$AA13>=AF$10)`

Are there better formulas, more particularly for the orange % task completed? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? Is there a problem with the formulas you currently use?

Comment: The problem with the one i use is: if I have 100% in column AD it will not only color the square its designated to, but it will add two more blocks to the right making it look as if it is a 3 day long task but in reality it is only 1. In addition another issue is, if I set 50% for example in the first task, it will cover about 90% of the bar instead of 50% orange

Comment: You should add information by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71055520/edit) perhaps a screen shot highlighting the problem and showing what the desired result is would also be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I create a vba solution, looks like
[image]

code is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim shp As Shape
  Dim rngTrefferStart As Range
  Dim rngTrefferEnde As Range
  Dim rngBereich As Range
   
  If Target.Column = 3 Then
     
   With Tabelle1
   
    Set rngTrefferStart = .Rows(2).Find(what:=CDate(Target.Offset(0, -1).Value), lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not rngTrefferStart Is Nothing Then
     
     Set rngTrefferEnde = .Rows(2).Find(what:=CDate(Target.Value), lookat:=xlWhole)
     If Not rngTrefferEnde Is Nothing Then
          
      Set rngBereich = .Range(.Cells(Target.Row, rngTrefferStart.Column), .Cells(Target.Row, rngTrefferEnde.Column))
      ShapeEntfernen rngBereich
         
      If Target.Value = "" Then ShapeEntfernen rngTrefferStart: Exit Sub
         
         Set shp = rngBereich.Worksheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, _
                Left:=rngTrefferStart.Left, _
                Top:=Target.Top, _
                Width:=rngBereich.Width, _
                Height:=rngTrefferStart.Height)
                
              shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
              
              shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = .Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value
              shp.TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
              shp.TextFrame2.HorizontalAnchor = msoAnchorNone
              ShapeAktualisieren rngBereich, .Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value, .Cells(Target.Row, 4).Value
     End If
    End If
  
  End With
  
  End If
 
 If Target.Column = 1 Then
  With Tabelle1
  Set rngTrefferStart = .Rows(2).Find(what:=Target.Offset(0, 1).Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not rngTrefferStart Is Nothing Then
     
     Set rngTrefferEnde = .Rows(2).Find(what:=Target.Offset(0, 2), lookat:=xlWhole)
     If Not rngTrefferEnde Is Nothing Then
          
     Set rngBereich = .Range(.Cells(Target.Row, rngTrefferStart.Column), .Cells(Target.Row, rngTrefferEnde.Column))
      ShapeAktualisieren rngBereich, .Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value, .Cells(Target.Row, 4).Value
     End If
     End If
  End With
 
 End If
 
  If Target.Column = 4 Then
  With Tabelle1
   Set rngTrefferStart = .Rows(2).Find(what:=Target.Offset(0, -2).Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not rngTrefferStart Is Nothing Then
     
     Set rngTrefferEnde = .Rows(2).Find(what:=Target.Offset(0, -1).Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
     If Not rngTrefferEnde Is Nothing Then
          
      Set rngBereich = .Range(.Cells(Target.Row, rngTrefferStart.Column), .Cells(Target.Row, rngTrefferEnde.Column))
      ShapeAktualisieren rngBereich, .Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value, .Cells(Target.Row, 4).Value
      
     End If
  
  End If
  End With
  End If
 
 End Sub
   

Sub ShapeEntfernen(rngBereich As Range)
 Dim shp As Shape
 
 For Each shp In Tabelle1.Shapes
  If InStr(shp.Name, "Drop") = 0 Then
  If Not Intersect(shp.TopLeftCell, rngBereich) Is Nothing Then
   
      shp.Delete
    End If
  End If
 
 Next shp

End Sub


Sub ShapeAktualisieren(rngBereich As Range, strZimmer As String, strZustand As String)
 Dim shp As Shape
 
 For Each shp In Tabelle1.Shapes
 If InStr(shp.Name, "Drop") = 0 Then
  If Not Intersect(shp.TopLeftCell, rngBereich) Is Nothing Then
    shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = strZimmer
    shp.TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
    shp.TextFrame2.HorizontalAnchor = msoAnchorNone
    
    Select Case strZustand
     Case "Früh"
      shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(146, 208, 80)
     Case "Spät"
      shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
     Case "Frei"
      shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
     Case Else
     shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(120, 120, 120)
    End Select
    
  End If
  End If
 
 Next shp

End Sub
```